# How do i deserialize a JSON with dynamic variables into a class

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file with different variables in each line.

Example:

```
{"Id":1,"Name":"John","Age":34}
{"Id":2,"Name":"Peter","Married":"Yes"}
```

If I define a class:

```
class Employee
{
    Id Int64 {get ;set ;} 
    Name string {get ;set ;}
    Age Int64 {get ;set ;}
}
```

How do I de-serialize the JSON into the object employee if i am using the statement

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(serialized);
```

How do I account for any dynamic variables which I do not have defined in my class?

Comment: What do you want to do with those other properties? If you don't know them ahead of time you can't use them directly in the code. Is it for display? Or to pass to some other system?

Comment: Age as `Int64`?  They must eat heathly, real healthy, on your planet

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the properties beforehand, you can serialise directly to a `Dictionary<string, string>`. For example:

```
var json = @"{""Id"":2,""Name"":""Peter"",""Married"":""Yes""}";
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

foreach (var element in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {element.Key}, Value: {element.Value}");
}
```

And the output would be this:

```
Key: Id, Value: 2
Key: Name, Value: Peter
Key: Married, Value: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let me point out that having objects with unknown properties makes no sense. How would you be able to work with such objects in the rest of your code? You can explain what you will do with those objects if you want us to help you find a suitable solution.

Having said that, you can create a class with all possible properties, and make all those properties nullable. In your examples, it can be:

```
class Employee {
    int Id { get; set; } 
    string Name { get; set; }
    int? Age { get; set; }
    bool? Married { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I assumed that the `Id` is always there, so I didn't make it nullable, and that `Married` is boolean with `true`/`false` values, rather than `yes`/`no` in your example.